# Load custom template with dynamic path

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I have an obsolete web project with webpack 1.14.0. In the project, the `html-webpack-plugin` is used to generate HTML file. This is the webpack configuration:

```js
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'title',
      banner: banner,
      publicPath: (debug ? `http://${ipToUse}:8080/` : fullDeployPath),
      chunks: ['home'],
      is_debug: debug,
      template: path.join(__dirname, 'lib', 'template.ejs'),
      inject: 'body',
      filename: 'index.html',
    }),
```

And this is a template.ejs file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <%= require('html!./cmp.html') %>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.publicPath %>assets/touch-icon.png" />
    <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.publicPath %>assets/touch-icon.png" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.publicPath %>assets/logo.ico" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main-app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I load there a custom template (`require('html!./cmp.html')`). I use for that `html-loader`.

The question is: is it possible the require path `html!./cmp.html` to depend on `HtmlWebpackPlugin` configuration. In other words I want something like that:

```js
new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
   pathToTemplate: './some/path/head_template.html'
   // other options
)
```

and then in the template (or something like that):

```
<%= require('html!' + htmlWebpackPlugin.options.pathToTemplate) %>
```

It doesn't work for me. I guess loader and plugin are not run on the same time. When require is trying to load template `htmlWebpackPlugin.options.pathToTemplate` is not there.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I can do it much easier. It turns out that I can pass HTML string as an HtmlWebpackPlugin configuration, eg.

```js
new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
   snippet: '<h1>Some title</h1>'
   // other options
)
```

So I can read the file in my webpack config file, eg.

```js
const snippet = (() => {
  try {
    const snippet = fs.readFileSync(`./clients/${argv.client}/templates/snippet.html`);
    return snippet;
  } catch(err) {
    return '';
  }
})();


// later when I configure HtmlWebpackPlugin
new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
   snippet,
// other options
)
```

and in the template, I use it as any other option:

```html
<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.snippet %>
```